# Is there any way to tell if a transaction was produced by a multi-signature process?

Tags: transaction

IOTA has multisig as a way for the transaction to be signed by more than device before being sent.

Is there any way to tell if a transaction was produced by a multi-signature process?

Answer (score 1):

A normal signature can be stored in one, two or tree transactions. It depends on the security level selected by the user.

A transfer from a normal address with security level 3 requires a bundle with at least 3 transactions to store the signature, and usually an additional transaction is required for the remainder.

A transfer from **a multisig address will usually requires more than 3 transactions to store the signature** because the *security level* of the multisig transfer is the sum of all security level of all individuals signing the bundle.

So when Alice and Bob agree to transfer from their multisig address: if Alice use a security level 3  and Bob security level 2 : the final bundle requires five transaction to store the signature (+1 if there is a remainder).

On the other hand, if Alice and Bob uses both security level 1 : the final bundle only requires 2 transactions to store the signature... and (unless I miss something) there is no way to make a distinction between this bundle and a standard bundle with security level 2.